# how to generate data model from draft v7 JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am attempting to generate a data model matching a JSON schema.

the schema is draft v7 and i cannot find any IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse) or online resource that can consume it and allow me to generate example json messages.

I either see no error messages at all or a generic one saying an error occurred when i attempt to load the schema.

surely there must be a standard approach to consuming a v7 json schema and generating json messages from it.

what am i doing wrong

Comment: Did you also try JSONBuddy (https://www.json-buddy.com)? The tool can generate sample data from any JSON Schema.

Comment: @Clemens, i didnt as thats a windows application and i have mac book pro, its my employers machine and i cannot install software applications that are not approved